# can't launch kex on wsl2 : error 10061

Tags: kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tigervnc

I recently had to disable-reenable my WSL2 on windows (because i needed to launch a VM) and after restarting, it seems like my kex stopped working.

When I simply type "kex", I get the typical "Error connecting to the KeX server". A small window opens and says "unable to connect to socket: Connection refused (10061)".

I'm used to temporary errors with kex that just require `kex --stop` or `kex kill` or similar to be fixed, but none of those worked.
When I do that however, I get (2 or 4 times) the following message : `tigervncserver: No matching VNC server running for this user!`
Doing it from my $HOME or with sudo didn't work either.

So, is there any way to fix this problem? All my packages are up-to-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first check if there is dbus exist or not so run this command
**sudo apt install dbus-x11**

run those command also **vncserver -kill** , **kex kill** ,**kex stop**

now run  **vncserver -localhost no**

and then to start just run **kex** command

Answer (score 0):

I've tried every solution I've found on the Internet so far,
but nothing has worked. 
My solution: I looked at the status via `kex status`:

```
/usr/bin/kex: line 266: tasklist.exe: command not found
```

Solution was found [at Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#running-windows-commands-fails-inside-a-distribution)
<sup>([also available in Russian](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#running-windows-commands-fails-inside-a-distribution))</sup>.

I've added `/mnt/c/Windows/system32` to $PATH.

Also I've created file `.wslconfig` in my User folder and added these lines:

```
[wsl2]
localhostForwarding=true
```

Then I restarted the computer and it worked.

My current $PATH looks like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/usr/bin:
/sbin:
/bin:
/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:
/usr/lib/wsl/lib:
/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:
/mnt/c/Program Files/Python39/Scripts/:
/mnt/c/Program Files/Python39/:
/mnt/c/Windows/system32:
/mnt/c/Windows:
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:
/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that WSL is version 2. If it isn't download and run the update. Then verify it.
Then update kali to wsl 2. then verify that in command prompt: `wsl -l -v`. It should show kali installed and version 2.
Then install win-kex. It will take a while.
Then start it up in kali with `ken --win -s`. I found the seamless version didn't work. The window version did work.

This is on 2 Dell Windows 10 Pro machines.