# unable to connect socket: connection refused(10061)

Tags: kali-linux, gui, tightvnc

I am trying to run `kex --win -s` in kali linux in order to get the GUI but I am getting an error message:

```
Error: unable to connect socket: connection refused(10061)
```

Can you help

I have tried the following:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux

dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart

dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart

wsl --set-default-version 2

wsl --set-version kali-linux 2

sudo apt install -y kali-win-kex



kex --win -s
```

Start the vncserver to accept connection from all network address:

```
vncserver -localhost no
```

Check the status of the kex again by:

```
kex --status
```

It should now list the vnc sessions

Type the following command to start the kali windows:

```
kex --win -sl
```

If I run `vncserver -localhost no` I get the following:

```
Killing Xtigervnc process ID 29... success!
```

`tail /home/vi/.vnc/Vik.localdomain:5901.log`:

```
Xvnc TigerVNC 1.11.0 - built 2021-03-22 21:21
Copyright (C) 1999-2020 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12010000, The X.Org Foundation


Mon May 24 18:42:53 2021
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0

Mon May 24 18:43:24 2021
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)

vncserver: /usr/bin/Xtigervnc did not start up, please look into '/home/vi/.vnc/Vik.localdomain:5901.log' to determine the reason! -1
```

Am new to kali linux

Comment: Sorry, are you running Windows (which would account for the `.exe`s) or are you running Kali linux? And the error message explicitly told you to look at `/home/vi/.vnc/Vik.localdomain:5901.log`; to tell what is wrong, we might need its contents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't launch kex on wsl2 : error 10061](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640049/cant-launch-kex-on-wsl2-error-10061)

Answer (score 1):

A note for everyone else having this issue: **Make sure you have WSL2 and not WSL1!** I spent hours trying to figure it out until I realized that I have WSL1.

- To get WSL 2 follow the instructions on [this page](http://aka.ms/wsl2).
- To upgrade an existing WSL1 kali-linux installation, open a Powershell with Administrator rights and type:

  ```
  wsl --set-version kali-linux 2
  ```

Note: [Referenced here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kalilinux/comments/lum8dw/wsl2_winkex_refused_to_connect/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to [stop](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-is-now-available-in-windows-insiders/) all running distributions and WSL 2 light utility virtual machines.

```
wsl --shutdown
```

and login to Win-KeX.

```
kali
kex
```

It worked on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried every solution I've found on the Internet so far,
but nothing has worked. 
My solution: I looked at the status via `kex status`:

```
/usr/bin/kex: line 266: tasklist.exe: command not found
```

Solution was found [at Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#running-windows-commands-fails-inside-a-distribution)
<sup>([also available in Russian](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#running-windows-commands-fails-inside-a-distribution))</sup>.

I've added `/mnt/c/Windows/system32` to $PATH.

Also I've created file `.wslconfig` in my User folder and added these lines:

```
[wsl2]
localhostForwarding=true
```

Then I restarted the computer and it worked.

My current $PATH looks like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/usr/bin:
/sbin:
/bin:
/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:
/usr/lib/wsl/lib:
/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:
/mnt/c/Program Files/Python39/Scripts/:
/mnt/c/Program Files/Python39/:
/mnt/c/Windows/system32:
/mnt/c/Windows:
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:
/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:
```